# Confusion about when Solace properties are effective

Tags: java, docker, jms, solace

We have a solace broker running in a docker container. When we create a JNDI Connection Factory there are default properties such as

- Reconnect Retry Attempts
- Connect Retry Attempts
- Connect Retry Attempts per Host

and so on

When we establish a producer using JMS we give properties like so

```java
env.put(SupportedProperty.SOLACE_JMS_JNDI_CLIENT_ID, config.getJndiClientID());
env.put(SupportedProperty.SOLACE_JMS_PROP_SENDER_ID, config.getSenderID());
env.put(SupportedProperty.SOLACE_JMS_VPN, config.getVpn());
env.put(SupportedProperty.SOLACE_JMS_JNDI_CONNECT_RETRIES, 0);
env.put(SupportedProperty.SOLACE_JMS_JNDI_RECONNECT_RETRIES, 0);
env.put(SupportedProperty.SOLACE_JMS_JNDI_CONNECT_RETRIES_PER_HOST, 0);
```

however at the run-time of application and at the point when connection is getting established it seems that these properties that I set on the client side take no effect. Specifically I was able to test that by stopping the docker container of solace and seeing that it is trying to reconnect 3 times which is what happens to be the default is on the broker side.

Therefore, the question, how to force the override of these properties on the client side, if at all possible? Under what circumstances does setting these properties on a client side take affect?

Answer (score 1):

Loading of a JMS ConnectionFactory over JNDI is, per definition, a two step process: first the API connects to JNDI and then loads whatever JMS ConnectionFactory object has been created.

Property SOLACE_JMS_JNDI_CONNECT_RETRIES (note the *JNDI*) is actually the parameter for the first step ! It defines the #retries for contacting JNDI. If you want to change the definition of the loaded JMS ConnectionFactory, you need to do this in your Solace administrator. For example within admin GUI as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you use env.put(), you are trying to set the JMS Property using the Initial Context.
But these properties could also be set through the JNDI properties file as well as the command line.

If you turn on the API debugging, you should be able to see which value is taken from where.

Now, once you are able to connect with the JNDI connection factory on the broker, the values will be taken from the broker side.